# How to access Honeywell wireless door/window sensor data?

Tags: security

I recently moved and our new home has several home security sensors, on most doors as well a motion sensor in the home. The sensors were part of an ADP security system which is not currently enabled.

I would like to access the sensor data so that I can make use of them outside of the ADP system. I assume they're still functioning (wireless, battery operated) despite the ADP system being offline. My end goal is to have the sensors report to some kind of receiver system of my own design so that I can make use of the information in a programatic way (*I'm a software engineer by trade*).

How do I access and/or receive the sensor information? They appear to be the [Honeywell 5816](https://www.security.honeywell.com/product-repository/5816-5816br) line of door/window sensors. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

use the honeywell receiver perhaps?

https://www.security.honeywell.com/product-repository/5881enhc